# Phonegap Developer App, Custom IOS Build

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to create a custom build for phonegap app for ios.
This is the manual I found for doing so:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer

After installing node.js and npm, I did the following in mac terminal:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer.git
$ cd phonegap-app-developer/
$ npm install
```

due to some permission errors, I decided to do the following:

```
$sudo chmod -R 777 phonegap-app-developer/
```

and after that:

```
$ npm run phonegap -- build ios
```

After running the above line, the process of building starts and ends with the following message:

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
Command finished with error code 0: /Users/user/Desktop/phonegap/phonegap-app/phonegap-app-developer/platforms/ios/cordova/build
[phonegap] completed 'cordova --verbose build ios'
```

After this step I go to "platforms" folder and then into "ios" and then I open the xcodeproj file, change app identity and then install the app on my phone. (with the latest version of xcode I can install my projects on my phone without a developers account)

After creating a new phonegap project and serving it, I open the app and connect to server successfully.(download and extract work fine)

But the "deviceready" event never gets fired!!! And the loaded phonegap project doesnt work.
I also conencted to this server with an android device and It worked just fine. So there is something wrong with the custom app I just built.
Also the original phonegap app (that I downloaded from appstore) works fine.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this issue to phonegap-app-developer repository on github and they answered.
Actually this was a bug with the master branch and they corrected it on "dev" branch.
So I checked out branch dev and It solved my problem.